# Add quicklaunch link with querystring parameter programatically

Tags: development, quick-launch

I want to add some links to Quicklaunch bar. The link needs to have query string parameters, eg.: `/sites/project/default.aspx?mode=filter`

```
string url = "/sites/project/default.aspx?mode=filter";
string title = "Filter";

SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode newnode = new SPNavigationNode(title, url, false);
web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(newnode);
```

Unfortunatelly, this code adds quicklaunch link without the parameter, ie.: `/sites/project/default.aspx`.

What is correct way to add link with params from code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the SPNavigationNode make the isExternal variable as true . Check this article [Link](http://www.thedotnotcorner.com/2012/12/12/add-a-query-string-parameter-to-spnavigationnode/)

Comment: Or change constructor to: new SPNavigationNode(title, url, true);
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old post, but setting `IsExternal` to `true` works.. but isn't the correct way of adding Query String..

Here is how you add a Query String:

```
string url = "/sites/project/default.aspx";
string title = "Filter";

SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
var newNode = new SPNavigationNode(title, url, false);
quickLaunch.AddAsLast(newNode);
newNode.Properties["UrlQueryString"] = "mode=filter";
newNode.Update();
```

Reference:

[programmatically passing navigation node url with querystring](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1e539705-5a5a-4ca0-9dc9-8822b0539bc0/programmatically-passing-navigation-node-url-with-querystring)

Comment: Nice solution, however this works only when publishing is enabled. See : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2008/07/24/the-buzz-with-urlquerystring-in-sharepoint-navigation.aspx